# How to use pydantic's from_orm using a Generic Class?

Tags: database, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I'm writing a generic repository class (with pydantic and sqlalchemy) and I'd like to remove the need to supply the result pydantic model as an argument like so:

```
class DatabaseRepository(Generic[T]):

    @classmethod
    async def get(cls, obj_id, model_class: Type[T]) -> T:
        table = cls.get_table()
        async with AsyncSession(cls.engine) as session:
            result = await session.get(table, obj_id)
        return model_class.from_orm(result)
```

I have found online that [get_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) is supposed to allow me to access the model given to the generic class, but it doesn't work for me:

```
get_args(cls.__bases__)[0].from_orm(result)
```

`cls.__bases__` is an empty list, and the pydantic model isn't there to access. Am I accessing the wrong property? I have tried other properties like `__orig_bases__` and that's also an empty list.

Note: T is a Pydantic model derived from BaseModel.

Is there a way to remove the model_class argument I showed above and still use the from_orm() method inside a generic class?

Comment: 1.) What is `get_args`? (link docs please) 2.) What (type) is `cls`? 3.) What does it mean that "it doesn't work" for you? Please give a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you, I added the missing information.

Comment: Interesting. I already learned a bunch while doing research for this. Can you give a simplified **usage** example for this generic class? How you would like to specify and instantiate it? You already noted that you want `T` to be the Pydantic model class, so I assume `DatabaseRepository[YourModel]` is at least partly how you want to specify it. But what then? Can you walk me through an abstracted use case? (No specifics) Asking because it depends on whether you want to subclass it later or instantiate it directly for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

I posted the **generalized** question and answer here:

[**Access type argument in any specific subclass of user-defined Generic[T] class**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746553)

---

I am assuming you will be using that `get` method in **specifc** subclasses of your generic `DatabaseRepository`. I can't see any other sensible use case for it.

Here is how you could do it in your case: (full working example)

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, Optional, Type, TypeVar, get_args, get_origin

from pydantic import BaseModel


# `DatabaseRepository` must be parameterized with exactly one type variable.
M = TypeVar("M", bound=BaseModel)


class DatabaseRepository(Generic[M]):
    _model: Optional[Type[M]] = None  # set in specified subclasses

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        """
        Initializes a subclass of `DatabaseRepository`.

        Identifies the specified `DatabaseRepository` among all base classes and
        saves the provided type argument in the `_model` class attribute
        """
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for base in cls.__orig_bases__:  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
            origin = get_origin(base)
            if origin is None or not issubclass(origin, DatabaseRepository):
                continue
            type_arg = get_args(base)[0]
            # Do not set the attribute for GENERIC subclasses!
            if not isinstance(type_arg, TypeVar):
                cls._model = type_arg
                return

    @classmethod
    def get_model(cls) -> Type[M]:
        if cls._model is None:
            raise AttributeError(
                f"{cls.__name__} is generic; model unspecified"
            )
        return cls._model

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, obj_id: int) -> M:
        model = cls.get_model()
        return model(id=obj_id)


def demo() -> None:
    class MyModel(BaseModel):
        id: int

    class Mixin:
        @classmethod
        def print_model_name(cls) -> None:
            print(getattr(cls, "_model").__name__)

    class SpecificRepository(Mixin, DatabaseRepository[MyModel]):
        @classmethod
        def print_data(cls, obj_id: int) -> None:
            print(cls.get(obj_id))

    instance = SpecificRepository.get(123)
    assert isinstance(instance, MyModel)
    print(instance)
    SpecificRepository.print_model_name()
    SpecificRepository.print_data(456)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

The output:

```
id=123
MyModel
id=456
```

No `mypy` complaints in `--strict` mode.

---

I left out the SQLAlchemy database query in your `get` method and made it non-`async` just to have a very simple working demo, but I am sure you get the idea.

I also added the `Mixin` class and that `print_data`-method just to demonstrate that everything works as expected.

A benefit of this solution is the way it plays nice with IDEs like PyCharm, which produce useful auto-suggestions depending on the model `M` returned by `get_model`.

The `get_model` method is called inside `get` just to have the exception in place, if you accidentally try to call it from a generic class.

Hope this helps.