# Access type argument in any specific subclass of user-defined Generic[T] class

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, base-class

### Context

Say we want to define a custom generic (base) class that inherits from [`typing.Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types).

For the sake of simplicity, we want it to be parameterized by a single [type variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) `T`. So the class definition starts like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class GenericBase(Generic[T]):
    ...
```

### Question

Is there a way to access the type argument `T` **in any specific subclass** of `GenericBase`?

The solution should be universal enough to work in a subclass with additional bases besides `GenericBase` and be independent of instantiation (i.e. work on the class level).

The desired outcome is a class-method like this:

```py
class GenericBase(Generic[T]):

    @classmethod
    def get_type_arg(cls) -> Type[T]:
        ...
```

### Usage

```py
class Foo:
    pass

class Bar:
    pass

class Specific(Foo, GenericBase[str], Bar):
    pass

print(Specific.get_type_arg())
```

The output should be `<class 'str'>`.

### Bonus

It would be nice if all relevant type annotations were made such that static type checkers could correctly infer the **specific** class returned by `get_type_arg`.

### Related questions

- [Generic[T] base class - how to get type of T from within instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706180/) - This question focuses on direct **instances** of the custom generic class itself, not on *specified* subclasses.
- [How can I access T from a Generic[T] instance early in its lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985221/) - This is a variation on the previous one.
- [How to access the type arguments of typing.Generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572831/) - This is very close, but does not cover the possibility of other base classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

Grab the `GenericBase` from the subclass' `__orig_bases__` tuple, pass it to `typing.get_args`, grab the first element from the tuple it returns, and make sure what you have is a concrete type.

### 1) Starting with `get_args`

As pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50101934/19770795), the `typing` module for Python `3.8+` provides the [`get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) function. It is convenient because given a **specialization** of a generic type, `get_args` returns its type arguments (as a tuple).

Demonstration:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_args

T = TypeVar("T")

class GenericBase(Generic[T]):
    pass

print(get_args(GenericBase[int]))
```

Output:

```
(<class 'int'>,)
```

This means that once we have access to a **specialized** `GenericBase` type, we can easily extract its type argument.

### 2) Continuing with `__orig_bases__`

As further pointed out in the aforementioned post, there is this handy little class attribute `__orig_bases__` that is set by the `type` metaclass when a new class is created. It is mentioned [here in `PEP 560`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/#mro-entries), but is otherwise hardly documented.

This attribute contains (as the name suggests) the *original* bases as they were passed to the metaclass constructor in the form of a tuple. This distinguishes it from [`__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__), which contains the already *resolved* bases as returned by [`types.resolve_bases`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.resolve_bases).

Demonstration:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class GenericBase(Generic[T]):
    pass

class Specific(GenericBase[int]):
    pass

print(Specific.__bases__)
print(Specific.__orig_bases__)
```

Output:

```
(<class '__main__.GenericBase'>,)
(__main__.GenericBase[int],)
```

We are interested in the *original* base because that is the **specialization** of our generic class, meaning it is the one that "knows" about the type argument (`int` in this example), whereas the *resolved* base class is just an instance of `type`.

### 3) Simplistic solution

If we put these two together, we can quickly construct a simplistic solution like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_args

T = TypeVar("T")

class GenericBase(Generic[T]):
    @classmethod
    def get_type_arg_simple(cls):
        return get_args(cls.__orig_bases__[0])[0]

class Specific(GenericBase[int]):
    pass

print(Specific.get_type_arg_simple())
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
```

But this will **break** as soon as we introduce another base class on top of our `GenericBase`.

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_args

T = TypeVar("T")

class GenericBase(Generic[T]):
    @classmethod
    def get_type_arg_simple(cls):
        return get_args(cls.__orig_bases__[0])[0]

class Mixin:
    pass

class Specific(Mixin, GenericBase[int]):
    pass

print(Specific.get_type_arg_simple())
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    return get_args(cls.__orig_bases__[0])[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

This happens because `cls.__orig_bases__[0]` now happens to be `Mixin`, which is **not a parameterized type**, so `get_args` returns an empty tuple `()`.

So what we need is a way to **unambiguously** identify the `GenericBase` from the `__orig_bases__` tuple.

### 4) Identifying with `get_origin`

Just like `typing.get_args` gives us the type arguments for a generic type, `typing.get_origin` gives us the **unspecified** version of a generic type.

Demonstration:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_origin

T = TypeVar("T")

class GenericBase(Generic[T]):
    pass

print(get_origin(GenericBase[int]))
print(get_origin(GenericBase[str]) is GenericBase)
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.GenericBase'>
True
```

### 5) Putting them together

With these components, we can now write a function `get_type_arg` that takes a class as an argument and -- if that class is specialized form of our `GenericBase` -- returns its type argument:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_origin, get_args

T = TypeVar("T")

class GenericBase(Generic[T]):
    pass

class Specific(GenericBase[int]):
    pass

def get_type_arg(cls):
    for base in cls.__orig_bases__:
        origin = get_origin(base)
        if origin is None or not issubclass(origin, GenericBase):
            continue
        return get_args(base)[0]

print(get_type_arg(Specific))
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
```

Now all that is left to do is embed this directly as a class-method of `GenericBase`, optimize it a little bit and fix the type annotations.

One thing we can do to optimize this, is only run this algorithm **only once** for any given subclass of `GenericBase`, namely when it is defined, and then save the type in a class-attribute. Since the type argument presumably never changes for a specific class, there is no need to compute this every time we want to access the type argument. To accomplish this, we can hook into [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) and do our loop there.

We should also define a proper response for when `get_type_arg` is called on a (unspecified) generic class. An `AttributeError` seems appropriate.

### 6) Full working example

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, Optional, Type, TypeVar, get_args, get_origin


# The `GenericBase` must be parameterized with exactly one type variable.
T = TypeVar("T")


class GenericBase(Generic[T]):
    _type_arg: Optional[Type[T]] = None  # set in specified subclasses

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        """
        Initializes a subclass of `GenericBase`.

        Identifies the specified `GenericBase` among all base classes and
        saves the provided type argument in the `_type_arg` class attribute
        """
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for base in cls.__orig_bases__:  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
            origin = get_origin(base)
            if origin is None or not issubclass(origin, GenericBase):
                continue
            type_arg = get_args(base)[0]
            # Do not set the attribute for GENERIC subclasses!
            if not isinstance(type_arg, TypeVar):
                cls._type_arg = type_arg
                return

    @classmethod
    def get_type_arg(cls) -> Type[T]:
        if cls._type_arg is None:
            raise AttributeError(
                f"{cls.__name__} is generic; type argument unspecified"
            )
        return cls._type_arg


def demo_a() -> None:
    class SpecificA(GenericBase[int]):
        pass

    print(SpecificA.get_type_arg())


def demo_b() -> None:
    class Foo:
        pass

    class Bar:
        pass

    class GenericSubclass(GenericBase[T]):
        pass

    class SpecificB(Foo, GenericSubclass[str], Bar):
        pass

    type_b = SpecificB.get_type_arg()
    print(type_b)
    e = type_b.lower("E")  # static type checkers correctly infer `str` type
    assert e == "e"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo_a()
    demo_b()
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

An IDE like PyCharm even provides the correct auto-suggestions for whatever type is returned by `get_type_arg`, which is really nice.

### 7) Caveats

- The `__orig_bases__` attribute is not well documented. I am not sure it should be considered entirely stable. Although it doesn't appear to be "just an implementation detail" either. I would suggest keeping an eye on that.
- `mypy` seems to agree with this caution and raises a `no attribute` error in the place where you access `__orig_bases__`. Thus a `type: ignore` was placed in that line.
- The entire setup is for **one single type parameter** for our generic class. It can be adapted relatively easily to multiple parameters, though annotations for type checkers might become more tricky.
- This method **does not work** when called directly from a specialized `GenericBase` class, i.e. `GenericBase[str].get_type_arg()`. But for that one just needs to call `typing.get_args` on it as shown in the very beginning.