# Return type in a class method based on a class variable in Python

Tags: python, class, python-typing, typing

I am working with a codebase where you have couples of classes, always one dataclass and another execution class. The dataclass serves as a data collector (as the name suggests).

To "connect" the dataclass to the other class, I set a class variable in the other class to make clear what the relevant dataclass is. This works fine - I can use this class variable to instantiate the data class as I please. However, it is not clear to me how I can use this to specify for a given method that it will return an instance of the linked data class.

Take this example (executable):

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar

@dataclass
class Name(ABC):
    name: str


class RelatedName(ABC):
    _INDIVIDAL: ClassVar[Name]

    def return_name(self, **properties) -> Name:
        # There is a typing issue here too but you can ignore that for now
        return self._INDIVIDAL(**properties)  


@dataclass
class BiggerName(Name):
    other_name: str

class RelatedBiggerName(RelatedName):
    _INDIVIDAL: ClassVar[Name] = BiggerName


if __name__ == "__main__":
    biggie = RelatedBiggerName()
    biggiename = biggie.return_name(name="Alfred", other_name="Biggie").other_name
    print(biggiename)
```

The script works fine, but there is a typing problem. In the last but one line, you'll see the issue that the attribute `other_name` is undefined for the `Name` class. This is to be expected, but I am not sure how I can change the output type of `return_name` so that it will use the class that is defined in `_INDIVIDUAL`.

I tried `def return_name(self, **properties) -> _INDIVIDAL` but that naturally leads to `name '_INDIVIDAL' is not defined`.

Perhaps it is not possible what I am after. Is it at all possible to have typing within a class that depends on class variables? I'm interested in Python 3.8 and higher.

Comment: So, just so you know, `_INDIVIDAL: ClassVar[Name] = BiggerName` is incorrect, `BiggerName` is not an instance of `Name`. It is an instance of `type`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, good catch!

Comment: Two questions: 1) Do you actually **need** the class variable `_INDIVIDUAL` for anything other than the coupling of the two classes? 2) (Why) Do you need your `RelatedName` to be an `ABC`? Both relevant to possible solutions.

Comment: @DaniilFajnbergYes, I do need the class for other processing apart from typing. It has to be an ABC because it should not be initialiazable by itself.

Comment: Side question: Is it actually `_INDIVIDAL` (not `_INDIVIDUAL`)?

Comment: Ah, that's a typo. Should be _INDIVIDUAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @cherrywoods that a custom generic base class seems like the way to go here.

I would like to add my own variation that should do what you want:

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Generic, Optional, Type, TypeVar, get_args, get_origin


T = TypeVar("T", bound="Name")


@dataclass
class Name(ABC):
    name: str


class RelatedName(ABC, Generic[T]):
    _INDIVIDUAL: Optional[Type[T]] = None

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        """Identifies and saves the type argument"""
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for base in cls.__orig_bases__:  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
            origin = get_origin(base)
            if origin is None or not issubclass(origin, RelatedName):
                continue
            type_arg = get_args(base)[0]
            # Do not set the attribute for GENERIC subclasses!
            if not isinstance(type_arg, TypeVar):
                cls._INDIVIDUAL = type_arg
                return

    @classmethod
    def get_individual(cls) -> Type[T]:
        """Getter ensuring that we are not dealing with a generic subclass"""
        if cls._INDIVIDUAL is None:
            raise AttributeError(
                f"{cls.__name__} is generic; type argument unspecified"
            )
        return cls._INDIVIDUAL

    def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None:
        """Prevent instances from overwriting `_INDIVIDUAL`"""
        if name == "_INDIVIDUAL":
            raise AttributeError("Instances cannot modify `_INDIVIDUAL`")
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def return_name(self, **properties: Any) -> T:
        return self.get_individual()(**properties)


@dataclass
class BiggerName(Name):
    other_name: str


class RelatedBiggerName(RelatedName[BiggerName]):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    biggie = RelatedBiggerName()
    biggiename = biggie.return_name(name="Alfred", other_name="Biggie").other_name
    print(biggiename)
```

Works without problems or complaints from `mypy --strict`.

---

##### Differences

- The `_INDIVIDUAL` attribute is no longer marked as a `ClassVar` because that (for [no good reason](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations)) disallows type variables.
- To protect it from being changed by instances, we use a simple customization of the `__setattr__` method.
- You no longer need to explicitly set `_INDIVIDUAL` on any specific subclass of `RelatedName`. This is taken care of automatically during subclassing by `__init_subclass__`. (If you are interested in details, I explain them in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746553).)
- Direct access to the `_INDIVIDUAL` attribute is discouraged. Instead there is the `get_individual` getter. If the additional parentheses annoy you, I suppose you can play around with discriptors to construct a property-like situation for `_INDIVIDUAL`. (Note: You *can* still just use `cls._INDIVIDUAL` or `self._INDIVIDUAL`, it's just that there will be the possible `None`-type issue.)
- The base class is obviously a bit more complicated this way, but on the other hand the creation of specific subclasses is much nicer in my opinion.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic)?

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar, TypeVar, Generic, Type

T = TypeVar("T", bound="Name")

@dataclass
class Name(ABC):
    name: str


class RelatedName(ABC, Generic[T]):
    # This would resolve what juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, but mypy says:
    # ClassVar cannot contain type variables, so I guess your use-case is unsupported
    # _INDIVIDAL: ClassVar[Type[T]]
    # One option:
    # _INDIVIDAL: ClassVar
    # Second option to demonstrate Type[T]
    _INDIVIDAL: Type[T]

    def return_name(self, **properties) -> T:
        return self._INDIVIDAL(**properties)  


@dataclass
class BiggerName(Name):
    other_name: str

class RelatedBiggerName(RelatedName[BiggerName]):
    # see above
    _INDIVIDAL: Type[BiggerName] = BiggerName


if __name__ == "__main__":
    biggie = RelatedBiggerName()
    biggiename = biggie.return_name(name="Alfred", other_name="Biggie").other_name
    print(biggiename)
```

mypy reports no errors on this and I think conceptually this is what you want.
I tested on python 3.10.

Comment: So from the comment in your code it would seem that my use case is not really supported.

Comment: Indeed, type annotations of class variables of types are apparently unsupported. You either have to let loose on the ClassVar type annotation or annotating that the class variable is a type.

Comment: You could also look into creating a meta class for RelatedName. That could make type creation shorter, but isn't related directly to your typing issue.

Comment: If you are interested in the meta class solution, I can post that as well, but it isn't related to typing really. It enforces read-only access to _INDIVIDUAL via a class property, however.