# How to access args of generic class

Tags: python, python-typing

If I have a class A:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

class A(Generic[T]):
    a: T
```

How do I access the `Generic[T]` with the type-object `A`

`typing.get_origin(A[...]).__bases__` just returns a `<class 'typing.Generic'>` instead of `typing.Generic[~T]`

Comment: Can you show an example of how you create an instance of `A` and then want to access `T`?

Comment: For what purpose do you need to access `T` specifically? It would help to know, since there may be easier ways to achieve what you need.

Comment: @Grismar I want to inspect the typevars that `A` has defined using `Generic[T, ...]`. I'm only interested in the `T, ...` part, if that simplifies this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `__orig_bases__`. That is set by the `type` metaclass when a new class is created. It is mentioned [here in PEP 560](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/#mro-entries), but is otherwise hardly documented.

This attribute contains (as the name suggests) the *original* bases as they were passed to the metaclass constructor in the form of a tuple. This distinguishes it from [`__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__), which contains the already *resolved* bases as returned by [`types.resolve_bases`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.resolve_bases).

Here is a working example:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class A(Generic[T]):
    a: T

class B(A[int]):
    pass

print(A.__orig_bases__)  # (typing.Generic[~T],)
print(B.__orig_bases__)  # (__main__.A[int],)
```

Since it is poorly documented, I would be careful, where you use it. If you add more context to your question, maybe we'll find a better way to accomplish what you are after.

Possibly related or of interest:

[Access type argument in any specific subclass of user-defined Generic[T] class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746553)