# "Templated function" like in c++, but in python?

Tags: python, abstract-class, mypy

So I am solving a lot of Advent of Code tasks these days, and I set myself the added challenge of writing the code following as many best practices as possible. In particular, this means using `typing`, making the code as DRY as possible, and separating the data structures from the logical structures. However, I am running into a little bit of a problem.

Essentially, let me  lay out the parts of the code that certainly need to be written and written only once. These are

1. A set of 25 data types, let's call them `Data_i` where `i` is an integer between 1 and 25.
2. For each `i`, a method for parsing `Data_i` from a file. Let's assume, for the sake of argument, that this method is `load_data_i`.
3. A set of functions, let's say they are `function_i_j` where `i` is an integer between 1 and 25 and `i` is either 1 or 2. All functions return a string, and for each `i`, the function `function_i_j` accepts an instance of type `Data_i`.

Very basically, the code I could then write to handle a particular problem would be something like this:

```
def solve(problem_number, task_number):
    g = globals()
    g[f'function{problem_number}_{task_number}'](g[f'load_data_{problem_number}']())
```

however this, while quite DRY, is all sorts of hacky and ugly, and not really conducive to type hinting.

Some other ideas I had were:

- A `Solver` class with abstract methods `function_1` and `function_2`, and a method `solve` that just calls one of the two abstract methods. Then have 25 classes that inherit from `Solver`. The problem here is that each class inheriting from `Solver` will accept a different data type.
- A `Solver` class that also has `data` part of each solver, but that violates separating data from logic.
- Somehow using protocols, but I always hit one of the two problems above.

I feel more at home in `c++`, where the above problem could be solved by making `function_i_j` a templated class, and then explicitly instantiating it for the 25 data types.

Now, my two questions:

1. Can something similar be done in python, and if so, how?
2. If not, what other method, as mypy conforming as possible, will make my code "prettiest"?

---

Minimum example with only two data types:

```
Data1 = str
Data2 = float

def load_data_1(file_path: Path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return f.readlines()

def load_data_2(file_path: Path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return float(f.readline())

def function_1_1(data: Data01) -> str:
    return data.strip()

def function_1_2(data: Data01) -> str:
    return data.upper()

def function_2_1(data: Data02) -> str:
    return f'{data < 0}'

def function 2_2(data: Data02) -> str:
    return f'{data > 3.16}'

def main(problem_number: int, version_number: int) -> None:
    g = globals()
    function_to_call = g[f'function{problem_number}_{task_number}']
    data_loader = g[f'load_data_{problem_number}']
    data_path = f'/path/to/data_{problem_number}.txt'
    print(function_to_call(data_loader(data_path)))
```

Comment: It sounds (and TBH the question reads a bit abstractly) like what you are looking for is [ad-hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism), aka type-based dispatch where the correct function implementation is called based on the type of the argument (like in cpp templates). It's tough to really do that elegantly in Python. If it were really a problem (and for 25 different data types I get it) I would create a mapping between the string result of calling `type` on the argument and the correct implementation in a dict and dispatch that way in a single function.

Comment: Which is to say doing at the term level the same sort of table lookup that happens in statically typed languages with such dispatch mechanisms at the type level. Woohoo for being a human compiler.

Comment: @JaredSmith Hm, but from what I understand, that would still mean that when you call that dict, you can't prettily do any typing on the result, right?

Comment: You definitely can, the dict maps strings to functions which are (or at least can be) typed, it's kind of like a vtable of function pointers. The only hitch will be convincing the type checker that the argument type to the dispatching function is the correct argument type for the function in the table, but that's going to be an issue with any dynamic dispatching scheme, discriminating on a 25-type union is never fun.

Comment: " The only hitch will be convincing the type checker that the argument type to the dispatching function is the correct argument type for the function in the table,", yes, that was what I meant.

Comment: Generally with static analysis of dynamic languages there are certain compile-time legible runtime checks (like `isinstance`) that will convince the static analysis tool to narrow the type. I'm no expert on statically checking Python but I write Typescript for a living and it's a similar kind of situation there. If I were more of an expert I would write an answer instead of making suggestions in the comments, but I hope it helps point you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Just to be clear, a few questions: 1) When you say _"25 data types"_ you mean 25 classes, right? (We are in Python land, after all.) 2) `load_data_i` is a method of the class `Data_i`? 3) If `function_i_j` accepts an instance of `Data_i`, why are you calling it with a reference to `load_data_i` as its only argument inside `solve`?

Comment: Finally: Could you please edit your question and provide a concrete setup including all those components, but have `i` be just between `1` and `2`, just for the sake of clarity? Because as it stands right now, there are some inconsistencies in your write-up and a concrete example might help. I realize you want to keep it DRY, but just for illustrative purposes, write out the classes, methods and functions explicitly please. Then we can start thinking about optimization.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Well, yes, 25 classes. But more generally, 25 different structures. If the best way to encode them would be without classes (I doubt it though) I would be perfectly happy as well. 2) the load data can be a method of the class data_i, but can also be written out if that would make a nicer solution. 3) that was a typo, and it is fixed now.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Added minimal example that should explain everything I am trying to do.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying and amending your original post. And your problem with the current implementation is that the `function_to_call` and `data_loader` callables will be completely opaque to a static type checker, correct?

Comment: And another question: For the purposes of this exercise, the program will always get `problem_number` and `version_number` as inputs? In other words, you have no control over the inputs to `main`?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I believe you are focusing far too much on the current implementation. I do not yet have a fully working implementation. I am searching for the best architecture to use. The "current implementation" (better to call it "the example"), indeed, is problematic because the types are unclear to a static type checker. Regarding the control over inputs to main, sure, I have some control, but eventually, the data coming in will always have to be two numbers, or some equivalent structure.

Comment: Not trying to be deliberately annoying here. Maybe I just fail to understand, but IMHO your question is way too abstract and vague to be answered properly. It reads like a math problem (I love math), but it relates to programming and you ask how to conform to best practices, make it pretty etc. These questions require a concrete use case to be answered properly. I cannot make useful suggestions, if I don't have any constraints and you basically say "everything can be anything". I really tried to understand your issue, but the way it is right now, this will just turn into a back-and-forth.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Well you also have a concrete example, which I added according to your request. I would be happy with an answer to that as well, even though it would only skim the heart of my issue. So, for the sake of argument, let us say that indeed I do not have any control over the inputs to main. I believe that with this piece of information, my question is far from abstract. It has a concrete example, with concrete problems which you yourself pointed out in a comment  four up from this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

There is no equivalent to what you describe as a templated function in Python.

Getting an object by name dynamically (i.e. at runtime) will always make it impossible to infer its type for a static type checker. A type checker does not execute your code, it just reads it.

There are a few patterns and workarounds available to achieve code that more or less satisfies your constraints.

---

### The problem (?)

Here is how I understand the problem.

We are given *N* distinct data schemas (with *N* ≈ 25). Each of those schemas should be represented by its own data class. These will be our data types.

There should be a distinct function for each of our data classes that loads a file and parses its contents into an instance of that data class. We'll refer to them as our **load functions**. The logic for each of those load functions is given; they should all accept a file path and return an instance of their corresponding data class. There will consequently be *N* load functions.

For each data type, we are given *M* distinct algorithms (with *M* ≈ 2). Each of these algorithms shall have its own function that takes an instance of its corresponding class and returns a string. We'll call them our **solver functions**. Thus, there will be a total of *N* × *M* solver functions.

Each data type will be encoded with an integer `i` between 1 and *N*, which we will call the **problem number**. Each solver function for a given data type (i.e. for a given problem number) will be encoded with an integer `j` between 1 and *M*, which we will call the **version number**.

We are given *N* different files of data, each corresponding to a different data type. All the files reside in the same directory and are named `data_i.txt`, where `i` stands for its corresponding problem number.

The input to our main program will be two integers `i` and `j`.

The task is to load the `i`-th data file from disk, parse it into the corresponding data class' instance via its matching load function, call the `j`-th solver function defined for that data type on that instance, and print its output.

---

### Added constraints

- The code should be fully annotated and as type safe as possible.
- There should be clear separation between data (definition, parsing, loading) and logic (solver algorithms).
- Code repetition should be minimal.
- [PEP 20](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/), [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), and other pythonic best practices should be honored.

Where any of these constraints stand in conflict with one another, we should strive for a reasonable balance between them.

---

### Suggested solution

#### Code layout

Three files in one package (+ `__init__.py`):

- `data.py` containing data class definitions (and related code)
- `solver.py` containing the solver functions (and related code)
- `main.py` with the main function/script

I may reduce the number of blank lines/line breaks below what is typically suggested in style guides in the following to improve readability (reduce scrolling) on this site.

#### The `data` module

##### Considerations

Everything, literally everything (aside from keywords like `if` or `def`) in Python is an object and thus an instance of a class. Without further information we can assume that data of a certain schema can be encapsulated by an instance of a class. Python's standard library for example provides the [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module that may be useful in such situations. Very good third-party libraries exist, too.

To utilize the benefits that object-oriented programming provides, honor the DRY principle, and to improve code-reuse, and type clarity among other things, we can define one base data class that all our *N* data classes will inherit from.

Since the load function has an intimate 1:1 relationship with our data type, it is entirely reasonable to make it a method of our data classes. Since the logic is different for each individual data class, but each of them will have one, this is the perfect use case for abstract base classes (ABC) and the [`abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) decorator provided by the [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/abc.html) module. We can define our base class as *abstract* and force any subclass to implement a `load` method, aside from its own data fields of course.

##### Code

`data.py`

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pathlib import Path
from typing import TypeVar

__all__ = [
    "AbstractData",
    "Data1",
    "Data2",
    # ...
]

D = TypeVar("D", bound="AbstractData")

class AbstractData(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def load(cls: type[D], file_path: Path) -> D: ...

@dataclass
class Data1(AbstractData):
    x: str

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, file_path: Path) -> Data1:
        with file_path.open("r") as f:
            return Data1(x=f.readline())

@dataclass
class Data2(AbstractData):
    y: float

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, file_path: Path) -> Data2:
        with file_path.open("r") as f:
            return Data2(y=float(f.readline()))

...
```

##### Details

To be able to express that the type of the `Data1.load` class method is as subtype of `AbstractData.load`, we annotate the latter with a type variable in such a way that a type checker expects the output of that method to be of the specific type that it binds to (i.e. `cls`). That type variable further receives an upper bound of `AbstractData` to indicate that not *any* type object is valid in this context, but only subtypes of `AbstractData`.

#### The `solver` module

##### Considerations

Introduce a base solver class and a subclass for each problem number. Regarding abstractness and inheritance, the same ideas apply.

The difference this time is that we can make the base solver class **generic** in terms of the data class it deals with. This allows us (with a few tricks) to minimize code, while maintaining type safety.

A solver will have an attribute that can hold a reference to an instance of its corresponding data class. When initializing a solver, we can provide the path to a data file to immediately load and parse the data and save an instance of its data class in that attribute of the solver. (And/Or we can load it later.)

We will write a `get_solver` function that takes the problem number as its argument and returns the corresponding solver class. It will still use the approach of fetching it from the `globals()` dictionary, but we will make this as type safe, runtime safe, and clean as possible (given the situation).

To have knowledge of the narrowest possible type, i.e. the concrete solver subclass returned by `get_solver`, we will have no choice but to use the [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal)+[`overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) pattern. And yes, that means *N* distinct signatures for the same function. (Notice the trade-off "DRY vs. type safe" here.)

##### Code

`solver.py`

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generic, Literal, TypeAlias, TypeVar
from typing import get_args, get_origin, overload

from .data import *

__all__ = [
    "AbstractBaseSolver",
    "Solver1",
    "Solver2",
    "ProblemNumT",
    "VersionNumT",
    "get_solver",
]

D = TypeVar("D", bound=AbstractData)

class AbstractBaseSolver(ABC, Generic[D]):
    _data_type: type[D] | None = None  # narrowed in specified subclasses
    _data: D | None = None             # narrowed via instance property

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: object) -> None:
        """
        Initializes a subclass and narrows the `_data_type` attribute on it.

        It does this by identifying this specified class among all original
        base classes and extracting the provided type argument.

        Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746553/
        """
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for base in cls.__orig_bases__:  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
            origin = get_origin(base)
            if origin is None or not issubclass(origin, AbstractBaseSolver):
                continue
            type_arg = get_args(base)[0]
            # Do not set the attribute for GENERIC subclasses!
            if not isinstance(type_arg, TypeVar):
                cls._data_type = type_arg
                return

    @classmethod
    def get_data_type(cls) -> type[D]:
        if cls._data_type is None:
            raise AttributeError(
                f"{cls.__name__} is generic; type argument unspecified"
            )
        return cls._data_type

    def __init__(self, data_file_path: Path | None = None) -> None:
        if data_file_path is not None:
            self.load_data(data_file_path)

    def load_data(self, file_path: Path) -> None:
        self._data = self.get_data_type().load(file_path)

    @property
    def data(self) -> D:
        if self._data is None:
            raise AttributeError("No data loaded yet")
        return self._data

    @abstractmethod
    def function_1(self) -> str:
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def function_2(self) -> str:
        ...

class Solver1(AbstractBaseSolver[Data1]):
    def function_1(self) -> str:
        return self.data.x.strip()

    def function_2(self) -> str:
        return self.data.x.upper()

class Solver2(AbstractBaseSolver[Data2]):
    def function_1(self) -> str:
        return str(self.data.y ** 2)

    def function_2(self) -> str:
        return self.data.y.hex()


ProblemNumT: TypeAlias = Literal[1, 2]
VersionNumT: TypeAlias = Literal[1, 2]


@overload
def get_solver(problem_number: Literal[1]) -> type[Solver1]:
    ...

@overload
def get_solver(problem_number: Literal[2]) -> type[Solver2]:
    ...

def get_solver(problem_number: ProblemNumT) -> type[AbstractBaseSolver[D]]:
    cls_name = f"Solver{problem_number}"
    try:
        cls = globals()[cls_name]
    except KeyError:
        raise NameError(f"`{cls_name}` class not found") from None
    assert isinstance(cls, type) and issubclass(cls, AbstractBaseSolver)
    return cls
```

##### Details

That whole [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) / `get_data_type` hack is something I explain in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746553/). It allows utilizing the (specific) type argument passed to [`__class_getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__), when we subclass `AbstractBaseSolver`, at **runtime**. This allows us to only write the code for instantiating, loading and accessing the data class instance **once**, but still remain entirely type safe with it across all subclasses. The idea is to only write the `function_1`/`function_2` methods on each subclass after specifying the type argument and nothing else.

The code inside the `function_`-methods is obviously just for demo purposes, but it again illustrates type safety across the board quite nicely.

To be perfectly clear, the `ProblemNumT` type alias will need to be expanded to the number of problems/data types, i.e. `Literal[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`. The call signature for `get_solver` will likewise need to be written out *N* times. If anyone has a better idea than repeating the `overload`ed signature 25 times, I am eager to hear it, as long as the annotations remain type safe.

The actual implementation of `get_solver` is cautious with the dictionary lookup and transforms the error a bit to keep it in line with the typical Python behavior, when a name is not found. The last `assert` is for the benefit of the static type checker, to convince it that what we are returning is as advertised, but it is likewise an assurance for us at runtime that we did not mess up along the way.

#### The `main` module

Not much to say here. Assuming two function versions for each solver/data type, the `if`-statements are totally fine. If that number increases, well ... you get the idea. What is nice is that we know exactly which solver we get, depending on the integer we pass to `get_solver`. All the rest is also safe and pretty much self-explanatory:

`main.py`

```py
from pathlib import Path

from .solver import ProblemNumT, VersionNumT, get_solver


DATA_DIR_PATH = Path(__file__).parent


def main(problem_number: ProblemNumT, version_number: VersionNumT) -> None:
    solver_cls = get_solver(problem_number)
    data_file_path = Path(DATA_DIR_PATH, f"data_{problem_number}.txt")
    solver = solver_cls(data_file_path)
    if version_number == 1:
        print(solver.function_1())
    elif version_number == 2:
        print(solver.function_2())
    else:
        raise ValueError("Version number must be 1 or 2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(1, 2)
    main(2, 1)
```

If we put a `data_1.txt` with `foo` in its first line and a `data_2.txt` with `2.0` in its first line into the package's directory and run the script with `python -m package_name.main`, the output will be as expected:

```
FOO
4.0
```

There are no complaints from `mypy --strict` about that package.

---

### Closing thoughts

This is the best I could come up with after the little back and forth in the comments. If this illustrates a grave misunderstanding, feel free to point it out. It still seems to me that your question is very broad and allows a lot of room for interpretation, which makes pedants like me uncomfortable. I don't consider myself an expert, but I hope this still illustrates a few patterns and tricks that Python offers, when trying to write clean code.

Comment: You know, there are times I think that humanity made a mistake in inventing the internet. But then comes an answer like this and I realize that nah, it also allows awesome people to do awesome stuff just becuse they are awesome like that. Thank you!