# How to test __annotations__ member has same type as generic class parameter?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, python-typing

I want to be able to select only annotated members that have the same type as the parameter of generic in this base class:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")

class MarkFinder(Generic[T]):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls.marked = tuple(
            name for name, annotated_type in cls.__annotations__.items() 
            if some_condition(annotated_type)
        )
```

So that if I inherit:

```py
T2 = TypeVar("T2")

class Inheritor(MarkFinder[T2]):
    a: T2
    b: int
    c: T2
```

Then `Inheritor.marked` should just be `('a', 'c')`.

I have tried to replace `some_condition(annotated_type)` with:

`cls.__parameters__[0] is annotated_type` or `cls.__parameters__[0] == annotated_type`

but even though they have the same names, the types are not equal.

What is the correct condition? Or is this impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but with a few caveats. The crux of the approach as well as some of the things to keep in mind are explained in the following post, so I suggest you read it first:

[Access type argument in any specific subclass of user-defined Generic[T] class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746553)

The **TL;DR** is to grab the the type argument from the *original* base class (which will be a [generic alias type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias)) from `__orig_bases__` and compare the annotations against that (for identity).

From the way you phrased your question, I assume you only want this to apply to **type variables** and not to *specific* type arguments. Here is how you could do it:

```py
from typing import Any, ClassVar, Generic, TypeVar, get_args, get_origin


T = TypeVar("T")


class MarkFinder(Generic[T]):
    marked: ClassVar[tuple[str, ...]] = ()

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for base in cls.__orig_bases__:  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
            origin = get_origin(base)
            if origin is None or not issubclass(origin, MarkFinder):
                continue
            type_arg = get_args(base)[0]
            if not isinstance(type_arg, TypeVar):
                return  # do not touch non-generic subclasses
            cls.marked += tuple(
                name for name, annotation in cls.__annotations__.items()
                if annotation is type_arg
            )
```

Usage demo:

```py
T2 = TypeVar("T2")


class Child(MarkFinder[T2]):
    a: T2
    b: int
    c: T2


T3 = TypeVar("T3")


class GrandChild(Child[T3]):
    d: T3
    e: str


class SpecificDescendant1(GrandChild[int]):
    f: int


class SpecificDescendant2(GrandChild[str]):
    f: float


print(Child.marked)                # ('a', 'c')
print(GrandChild.marked)           # ('a', 'c', 'd')
print(SpecificDescendant1.marked)  # ('a', 'c', 'd')
print(SpecificDescendant2.marked)  # ('a', 'c', 'd')
```

The check for the `type_arg` not being a `TypeVar` instance is important. Without it, that `SpecificDescendant1` subclass would also have `'f'` in its `marked` tuple. (If that is what you want, just remove that check from the base class' `__init_subclass__` method.)